# Why is my infowindows not showing up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a map which uses custom tiles I pulled from World of Warcraft, I have gotten markers to show up and i'm pretty sure I'm doing infowindows correctly but they are not showing up when I click on the marker?

[Relevant JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eLgmnct/1/)

Script:

```
$(function () {
    initialize();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#map').css('width', $(window).width() + 'px');
        $('#map').css('height', ($(window).height() - 35) + 'px');
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        hash_init(); // keeps the map centered correctly
    }).resize();
});

function CustomMapType() {}
CustomMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
CustomMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 7;
CustomMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
    var baseURL = 'http://d1m6g5gl70bc4l.cloudfront.net/';
    baseURL += zoom + '_' + coord.x + '_' + coord.y + '.png';
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#1B2D33';
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + baseURL + ')';
    return div;
};

CustomMapType.prototype.name = "Custom";
CustomMapType.prototype.alt = "Tile Coordinate Map Type";
var map;
var CustomMapType = new CustomMapType();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 7,
        isPng: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.705, -35.200),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['custom', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        }

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set('custom', CustomMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('custom');

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    xmlUrl = "markers.xml";

    loadMarkers();

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//
// Google Maps functions 
//

// Google Maps vars
var myLatlng; // Add the coordinates
var mapOptions = {};
var geocoder;
var map;
var defaultZoom = 10;
var image;
var xmlUrl;
var infoWindow;
var markers;
var contactUrl;



function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            //request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function loadMarkers() {
    map.markers = map.markers || [];
    // downloadUrl(xmlUrl, function (data) {
    // var xml = data.responseXML;
    var xmlString ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><markers><marker id="1" name="Goldshire" address1="Azeroth" address2="info" address3="info" city="info" postcode="info" lat="35.120" lng="33.706" /></markers>';

        var xml = xmlParse(xmlString);
        markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var marker_image = markers[i].getAttribute('markerimage');
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address1")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("address2")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("address3")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("postcode");
            var image = {
              url: marker_image,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 132),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(71, 132)
            };
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<div class='infowindow'><b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + '<br/></div>';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: image,
                title: name
            });
            map.markers.push(marker);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
//    });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
/**
 * Parses the given XML string and returns the parsed document in a
 * DOM data structure. This function will return an empty DOM node if
 * XML parsing is not supported in this browser.
 * @param {string} str XML string.
 * @return {Element|Document} DOM.
 */
function xmlParse(str) {
    if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
    }

    if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
        return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
    }

    return createElement('div', null);
}
```

Sorry if its an easily fixed problem, its my first time with google maps.

Comment: are you getting markers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant get markers from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314704/cant-get-markers-from-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
     var marker_image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png';
```

instead of

```
 var marker_image = markers[i].getAttribute('markerimage');
```

or add `markerimage` in the xml.

since your code gives error for `url` because the image string is not available that's why you are not getting infowindow.

**// see demo here**

```js
$(function () {
     initialize();
     $(window).resize(function () {
         $('#map').css('width', $(window).width() + 'px');
         $('#map').css('height', ($(window).height() - 35) + 'px');
         google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
         hash_init(); // keeps the map centered correctly
     }).resize();
 });

 function CustomMapType() {}
 CustomMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
 CustomMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 7;
 CustomMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
     var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
     var baseURL = 'http://d1m6g5gl70bc4l.cloudfront.net/';
     baseURL += zoom + '_' + coord.x + '_' + coord.y + '.png';
     div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
     div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
     div.style.backgroundColor = '#1B2D33';
     div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + baseURL + ')';
     return div;
 };

 CustomMapType.prototype.name = "Custom";
 CustomMapType.prototype.alt = "Tile Coordinate Map Type";
 var map;
 var CustomMapType = new CustomMapType();

 function initialize() {
     var mapOptions = {
         minZoom: 2,
         maxZoom: 7,
         isPng: true,
         mapTypeControl: false,
         streetViewControl: false,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.705, -35.200),
         zoom: 3,
         mapTypeControlOptions: {
             mapTypeIds: ['custom', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
             style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
         }

     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

     map.mapTypes.set('custom', CustomMapType);
     map.setMapTypeId('custom');

     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     xmlUrl = "markers.xml";

     loadMarkers();

 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

 //
 // Google Maps functions 
 //

 // Google Maps vars
 var myLatlng; // Add the coordinates
 var mapOptions = {};
 var geocoder;
 var map;
 var defaultZoom = 10;
 var image;
 var xmlUrl;
 var infoWindow;
 var markers;
 var contactUrl;



 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
     var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();

     request.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (request.readyState == 4) {
             //request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
             callback(request, request.status);
         }
     };

     request.open('GET', url, true);
     request.send(null);
 }

 function loadMarkers() {
     map.markers = map.markers || [];
     // downloadUrl(xmlUrl, function (data) {
     // var xml = data.responseXML;
     var xmlString ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><markers><marker id="1" name="Goldshire" address1="Azeroth" address2="info" address3="info" city="info" postcode="info" lat="35.120" lng="33.706" /></markers>';

         var xml = xmlParse(xmlString);
         markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
         console.log(markers);
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
             var marker_image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png';
             var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
             var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address1")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("address2")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("address3")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("postcode");
             var image = {
               url: marker_image,
               size: new google.maps.Size(71, 132),
               origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
               scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(71, 132)
             };
             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
             var html = "<div class='infowindow'><b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + '<br/></div>';
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: point,
                 icon: image,
                 title: name
             });
             map.markers.push(marker);
             bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
         }
//     });
 }

 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
         infoWindow.setContent(html);
         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
     });
 }
 /**
  * Parses the given XML string and returns the parsed document in a
  * DOM data structure. This function will return an empty DOM node if
  * XML parsing is not supported in this browser.
  * @param {string} str XML string.
  * @return {Element|Document} DOM.
  */
 function xmlParse(str) {
     if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
         var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
         doc.loadXML(str);
         return doc;
     }

     if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
         return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
     }

     return createElement('div', null);
 }
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
#gmnoprint {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<div class="topnav">
    <ul id="nav" xclass="topnav">
        <li><a href="/" class="current">Azeroth</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/outland/">Outland</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/deepholm/">Deepholm</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/outland/">Draenor</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="background: #1B2D33;"></div>
```